# Unit testing with Jasmine and Browserify and stubbing out require()s

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, browserify

For the below code I want to test the if/else in `someMethod`, but I don't have access to that require'd component. Is there any tricks to testing this stuff with Browserify? I can set `baz: Foo.bar()` on the proto, but then I'd have to do that for every require'd component I need to override.

```
var Foo = require('../foo/index.js');

var someClass = new SomeClass({
  someMethod: function () {
    var baz = Foo.bar();
    if (baz == 'hello') {
      return 1
    }
    else {
      return 0
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check out rewireify or proxyquireify.  They will allow you to manipulate your "var Foo = require" statement in your test.  But yes, you will have to do this for each require statement you want to mock.  You also may want to check out Facebook's Jest, that mocks all of your require statements for you automatically.